# Why is facebook.com/sharer posts a small square thumbnail image instead of large rectangle?

Tags: facebook, share

When I use the Facebook share code with the s= option, Facebook displays a small square thumbnail in the news feed instead of the new larger rectangular thumbnail image.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=My+Page+Title&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Findex.html%23lead&p%5Bsummary%5D=Check+out+my+page+by+clicking+here.&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fimages%2Fmy_meme.jpg

But if I use the share code below with the u= option facebook scrapes the og information off the page and displays the larger rectangle thumbnail image in the news feed.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%www.mysite.com

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large og:image in feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548770/large-ogimage-in-feed)