# Facebook Share showing small square thumbnail instead of large rectangle (og image is correct size)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer, og-meta

When I try to share from http://www.giftry.com I am given the small square thumbnail image instead of the large rectangle. The image linked to in the open graph meta tags is larger than Facebook's recommended 1200x630.

I've tried using the debugger, but there are no errors and everything looks correct. Any thoughts on what I can do?

Here are my og meta tags:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="I need your gift ideas!">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Giftry">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.giftry.com">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Come help me at Giftry — a place where gift givers unite to curate giftries full of fabulous gift ideas. Whether you create your own giftries or explore gift ideas for others, Giftry makes it easy to find ‘just the thing’, for anyone and any occasion. Now, let’s get gifting!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ec2-static.giftry.com/img/giftry_gift_surprise_large.jpg">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="356150731192079">
```

Comment: i think you're missing `og:type` set it to article and it should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large og:image in feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548770/large-ogimage-in-feed)

Comment: Looks like you are right @ThomasDavidPlat. I searched and couldn't find anything before posting. It looks like Facebook has relegated me to the small thumbnail image because they felt like it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @AdamAzad and looks like it is still the same. I'll give Facebook another day and see if it changes anything.

Comment: That's why I retracted from facebook development. I'm avoiding it whenever I can. I find the API pretty inconsistent and you are not properly notified about changes they seem to just happen and often you do something and don't know why something is (not) working... good luck with your issue though...

Comment: Hi Brandon, same problem with my page here: http://tringo-medical.blogspot.my/. It shows the small tiny little pencil icon image (Blogger Edit icon) instead of large banner image set at og:image. I tried commenting out that pencil icon image and re-scrape again but still doesn't work. Any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have find a way how to resolve this. When I remove fb:app_id and update url via debuger the rectangular image were shown as expected. Then I have created new fb:app_id and it works fine as well. If I turn back my old app id facebook show me small square thumbnail again.